# Angular reactive form validations pristine required recursive

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

Hi I have a problem with the form rective in angular 8 .. I have three recourse fields that are in the cycle as seen from the code. The array and fields section
At the time of validation being required, the pristine is broken and the validation does not work properly

```
<form [formGroup]="altriCampiForm">
      <div *ngIf="getFormType(sezione?.campi) === 'altro'">
        <div *ngFor="let campo of sezione?.campi; let i = index;">
          <label class="uxc-a-text-input uxc-a-text-input--with-label uxc-a-text-input--color-gray"
            data-t-name="UXCInput">
            <span class="uxc-a-text-input__wrap">
              <span class="uxc-a-text-input__label">{{campo}} *</span>
              <input aria-required="false"  type="text" name="campo" value=""
                class="uxc-a-text-input__input uxc-js-a-text-input__input"
                aria-describedby="validation-feedback-input-error" formControlName="campo">
            </span>
          </label>
        <!--problem with pristine
        <div [hidden]="altriCampiForm.controls(campo).pristine" class="text-danger">
            <p *ngIf="altriCampiForm.controls['campo'].errors != null">
              Campi obbligatori
            </p>
          </div>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

this is the controller 
export class FormSezioneComponent {
 altriCampiForm: FormGroup = this.newAltriCampiForm() // CF: Codice Fiscale

  private newAltriCampiForm (): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      campo: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ]))
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `altriCampiForm.controls[campo].pristine` instead of `altriCampiForm.controls(campo).pristine` ?

Comment: i try with this solution

Comment: but 2 input are required and one no

Comment: co.altriCampiForm.controls is not a function  not work your way